# xmlHttpRequest AJAX POST Reading the Posted value in MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Been struggling to find a solution to this one, despite the mass of useful information out there.

I have the following Javascript Function that is sending an AJAX call to my controller.

```
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('postLink');
        var sendstr = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            sendstr += ',';
            sendstr += posts[i].attributes.getNamedItem('onmouseup').value.substr(9, 1);
        }

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                var posts = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                addPostToList(posts.Title, posts.Description, posts.postID);

            }
        }
        ajax.open('POST', '@Url.Action("SAR", "posts")', true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-length', sendstr.length);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
        ajax.send(encodeURIComponent(sendstr));
```

The controller is as follows...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SAR(string r)
    {
        var s = Request.QueryString[0];
        return Content(Post.JSONSerialize());

    }
```

I have tried a number of different Data types as the Parameter and have still not received anything of use... I have also tried Request.Param, request.queryString, request.Form and a number of other 'solutions' that i have found on the web, it is passing only a comma seperated list of integers to the controller, stored as a string. How do i read this value when it has been sent off to the controller?

~I do not want a JQuery or JS Framework solution, i would like a native Javascript solution.

Comment: There are a lot of solutions to this. The main problem is that you're not telling your Controller that it should bind the data you're sending to the variable `r`. `ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); ajax.send("r="+encodeURIComponent(sendstr));` should be the easiest fix for your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.- Use JSON as your content-type.

2.- The string you are sending back has to match the parameter name you are expecting on your controller.

change your sendstr to the following format:

```
//Where r is the name of your parameter on the controller.
 var sendstr = '{"r":"STRING YOU WANT TO RETURN"}';
```

then change your ajax configuration to be

```
 ajax.open('POST', '@Url.Action("SAR","Controller")', true);
 ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
 ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', sendstr.length);
 ajax.send(sendstr);
```

I hope this works for you :)